# spring mvc framework hello world shows error 404

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am new to spring mvc framework and followed this **[site](http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/hello-world-example-spring-mvc-eclipse-annotation/)** for hello world tutorial

**error:**        the requested resource is not available

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>HelloWorldExampleWithSpring3MVCInEclipse</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/app-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**app-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.raistudies" />
    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**HelloWorldAction.java**

```
package com.raistudies.actions;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldAction {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView sayHello(Model model){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("hello");
        model.addAttribute("HelloMessage", "Hello World from My First Spring 3 mvc application");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World with Spring 3 MVC</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome! Spring MVC is working well.</h1><br />
        ${HelloMessage}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code and configuration seems correct. What URL are you trying to access from your browser? Are you accessing `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldExampleWithSpring3MVCInEclipse/hello.htm`?

Comment: yes i am using the same URL and even i created index.jsp, it's throwing the same error

Comment: I do not have HelloWorldAction controller in web inf but in the src folder. Does it make any difference

Comment: You can place the HelloWorldAction.java to the src folder. HelloWorldAction.class is generated in the WEB-INF/classes folder with the default Dynamic Web Project setting. You can check this setting in the Porject's Properties -> Deployment Assembly.

Comment: if everything seems to be fine , what could be the cause of the error

Comment: I have no ideas what the cause is, but cleaning your project (Menu bar -> Project -> Clean) is worth a try.

Comment: In `<url-pattern>` you have mentioned only .htm requests, while you are handling only /hello request in the controller class. Use '/' instead of ".htm"

Answer (score 1):

In **web.xml** when we replace "*htm" with "/", then the error of resource not available was solved.

Answer (score 1):

The original issue is because you're sending all requests ending `*.htm` to Spring:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But your controller is mapped to `/hello` without an extension.

Change the `@RequestMapping` in your controller to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldExampleWithSpring3MVCInEclipse/`, you need to create a WebContent/index.jsp in your project to make this URL work.

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<jsp:forward page="/hello.htm"></jsp:forward>
```

See the sample code [here](http://www.raistudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/HelloWorldSpring3MVCEclipseCode.zip).